# setting available sites in nginx on github actions cause error

Tags: github, nginx, github-actions, cicd, github-actions-runners

I have the following workflow setup:

```
    steps:
  - name: Checkout
    uses: actions/checkout@v3

  - name: Install Nginx
    run: |
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install -y nginx

  - name: Update NGINX configuration
    run: |
      echo "
      server {
          listen 80;
          server_name local.everestate.de;

          location / {
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header Host \$http_host;
              proxy_pass http://local.everestate.de;
          }
      }

      server {
          listen 80;
          server_name local.everestate.com;

          location / {
              proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header Host \$http_host;
              proxy_pass http://local.everestate.com;
          }
      }" | sudo tee -a /etc/nginx/sites-available/default > /dev/null

  - name: Log NGINX config
    run: |
      journalctl -xeu nginx.service
      cat /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

  - name: Start NGINX
    run: |
      sudo systemctl start nginx
      sudo systemctl status nginx.service
      sudo journalctl -xeu nginx.service
```

Adding this part "Update NGINX configuration"(echo ...) ends up with the following error

**Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xeu nginx.service" for details.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.**

Locally this config works perfectly, only on github actions I'm having this issue.
I was logging the /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file content and it looks like locally.
How can I fix it?

Edit:
sudo nginx -t gives me this back:
**nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "local.everestate.de" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:100
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting up resolvers and using variables resolved the problem:

```
 run: |
      echo "
      server {
          resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s ipv6=off;
          listen 80;
          server_name local.everestate.de;

          location / {
              set \$domain http://local.everestate.de;
              proxy_pass \$domain;
          }
      }

      server {
          resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s ipv6=off;
          listen 80;
          server_name local.everestate.com;

          location / {
              set \$domain2 http://local.everestate.com;
              proxy_pass \$domain2;
          }
      }"
```